# Nominal or real AC/DC power supply values

Tags: power-supply, ac-dc, rms

I have three older AC/DC power supplies with these nominal values:

- Input 120 Vac, 0.3 A, 60 Hz
  Output 16 Vdc, 900 mA
- Input 120 Vac, ?, 60 Hz
  Output 16 Vdc, 1 A
- Input 120 Vac, 60 Hz, 4 W
  Output 9 Vdc, 210 mA

When I take measurements of the voltages I obtain respectively:

- 22.71 Vdc
- 23.18 Vdc
- 15.30 Vdc

Why the differences? If I multiply the nominal values of the outputs by \$\sqrt{2}\$ (for RMS, but is it correct in Vdc?) I obtain similar values as measured. Or are the power supplies broken?

Comment: Re-measure the voltages at the rated load (or something close to it)

Comment: @winny thanks for your corrections on grammar

Answer (score 3):

They are unregulated power supplies. The nominal voltages are when they are under load (probably at the currents specified).

Such power supplies are usually just a transformer followed by a bridge rectifier and a smoothing capacitor. When there is no load the voltage is usually approximately equal to the loaded voltage multiplied by sqrt(2) as you noticed. That is because the capacitor charges up to the peak voltage out of the transformer when unloaded but will sag to something similar to the RMS voltage under load. There may be a significant amount of resistive drop as well that will cause a departure from that value.

Modern power supplies are usually switching power supplies where the transformer runs at a frequency of 100kHz or so. They are very much lighter (and usually smaller) for a given power. You can easily tell which type just by the weight. They are invariably regulated so the output voltage does not vary much with load.

Answer (score 1):

The power supplies are just transformers with diode bridge and bulk reservoir capacitor. Without any load, the capacitor does get charged to the sine wave peak voltage, which is approximately sqrt(2) times the AC RMS output from the transformer. The DC voltage will drop under load, so it is unlikely that they are broken.

Answer (score 0):

22.71 Vdc  /  16V  = **1.42**   @ 0.91A  , 16V/0.91A = 18 ohms  , 16  * 0.91=15.6VA  (not watts)
23.18 Vdc  / 16V   = **1.45**   @ 1A   , 16/1A =   16 ohms , 16 * 1A = 16VA
15.30 Vdc  /  9V   = **1.7**    @ 0.21A , 9V / .21A = 43 ohms  9V * 0.21 = 1.9 VA

No load unregulated supplies will have diode + cap peak above rms loaded voltage=  \$\sqrt(2)=1.414\$ plus typically **10% to 20% transformer loss**  =**1.55 to 1.70** times rated Voltage ( efficiency improves with power rating.)

These are all normal.

With the cost-reduction in magnetics using SMPS, and accurate active regulators < 3% tolerance from no load to full load, the above unregulated supplies are largely obsolete.